# Merge two arrays and omit all repeating elements

Tags: c, arrays, merge

I have 2 arrays. Input 1 and Input 2. Suppose input 1 has {1,1,2,3,3,4,5} and input 2 has {4,2,6,7,8}.  Merged array {1,1,2,3,3,4,5,4,2,6,7,8}

After sorting my merged array looks like {1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,8}

My output should be like {5,6,7,8} because those are non-repeating elements. It should have neither occurred twice in 1st nor once in 1st and once in 2nd.

I have put both the arrays into one single array(merged both). Sorted it and removed duplicates also.  I am getting the output like {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} but i should not get 1,2,3,4 as they all have occurred twice in the merged array.

Please help me to finish the program soon. Thanks in advance.

I cant use structures. Thats my task.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
    int a[10],b[10],c[10],i,j,n,n1,temp;
    clrscr();
    printf("enter the no of ele in array1\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("enter 1st array elements\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    printf("enter size of 2nd array");
    scanf("%d",&n1);
    printf("enter 2nd array elements\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&b[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        c[i]=a[i];
    }
    j=0;
    for(i=n;i<n+n1;i++)
    {
        c[i]=b[j];
          //    printf("\n2nd array values are %d",c[i]);
        j++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n+n1;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",c[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
        {
            if(c[j]>c[j+1])
            {
                temp=c[j];
                c[j]=c[j+1];
                c[j+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(j=0;j<n+n1;j++)
    {
        printf("sorted is %d\n",c[j]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<n+n1;i++)
    {
        if(c[i]==c[i+1])
        {
            temp=c[i];

         // printf("%d r d rep.ele\n",c[i]);
        }
        else
        printf("%d r d ele\n",c[i]);
    }

    getch();
}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: `Please help me to finish the program soon.` -- Did you even start?

Comment: If you're removing duplicates, you'll get `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}`, right?  Doesn't your algorithm require duplicates to filter them out?

Comment: Please paste your code fragment.

Comment: ***Show*** what you have tried

Comment: Assuming you have a merged and sorted array, an easy way to approach this problem is, for each element, only output it if it's neighbors (e.g., elements on either side) are different than it.

Answer (score 1):

Let us solve this in an inappropriate, yet funny, way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXINPUT 10

void pack(const int* k, int n, int* table)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    table[k[i]]++;
  }
}

void dump(const int* table)
{
  int flag = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < MAXINPUT; ++i)
  {
    if(table[i] == 1)
    {
      printf("%s%d", (flag) ? ", " : "", i);
      flag = 1;
    }
  }
}

int c[MAXINPUT];

int main(void)
{
  const int a[] = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5};
  const int b[] = { 4, 2, 6, 7, 8};
  pack(&a[0], sizeof(a)/sizeof(int), &c[0]);
  pack(&b[0], sizeof(b)/sizeof(int), &c[0]);
  dump(&c[0]);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t i, non_repeating_index = 0;

// allocate memory to hold the new array
int * non_repeating_elements = calloc(sizeof(int), merged_array_length);

// check if the first element is unique
if (merged_array_length >= 2 && merged_array[0] != merged_array[1])
    non_repeating_elements[non_repeating_index++] = merged_array[0];

// for all other elemnts check if it equals the ones around it
for (i = 1; i < merged_array_length -1; i++) {
    if (merged_array[i-1] != merged_array[i] && merged_array[i] != merged_array[i + 1])
        non_repeating_elements[non_repeating_index++] = merged_array[i];
}

// check the last element
if (merged_array_length >= 3 && merged_array[i-1] != merged_array[i])
    non_repeating_elements[non_repeating_index++] = merged_array[i];

// resize the array to conserve memory
non_repeating_elements = realloc(non_repeating_elements, sizeof(*non_repeating_elements) * non_repeating_index);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there! Don't try to be fancy, just create a struct with two int fields: value and count. Create an array of these structs and iterate through your sorted list. In the end you iterate through your array of structs and select all the values where the corresponding count is 1.

There are some details to sort out, like how large should your array of structs be, but hey, you're obviously not afraid of a bit of coding. If the array is bigger than you need, well... who cares as long as it's big enough?

Answer (score 0):

If you already sorted and merged the Arrays it's pretty simple: Just compare to the predecessor & successor. But some extra logic is needed to not run out of bounds.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  const int sortedMergedArray[] = {1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,8};
  const size_t mergedArrayLength = 12;
  for(size_t i=0; i<mergedArrayLength;i++){
    int predecessor = -1;
    int successor = -1;
    if(i >= 1) predecessor = sortedMergedArray[i-1];
    if(i <= mergedArrayLength-1) successor = sortedMergedArray[i+1];
    if(sortedMergedArray[i] != successor &&
        sortedMergedArray[i] != predecessor){
      printf("%d, ", sortedMergedArray[i]);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
5, 6, 7, 8,
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what are you doing in if loop. if(i>=1) and if(i<=mergedarraylength-1).

Comment: @user3018163 It prevents from using the predecessor & successor for the first / last element (because there is no predecessor/successor then) and you would run out of bounds. If you just would do `int predecessor = sortedMergedArray[i-1];
int successor = sortedMergedArray[i+1];` and leave the two if-conditionals out, for the first element it would try to get the predecessor at index -1 (which is a illegal array index), and for the last element it would try to get the successor at lastIndex+1 (which is illegal too, because the array index runs from 0...n-1).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have got another program. My question is "COMPARE 2 ARRAYS AND PRINT THE NON-REPEATED ELEMENTS". Suppose array 1={1,1,1,2,3,4} and array 2={2,3,6}. Output should be {1,4,6}. 2 and 3 has occured in both the arrays, so it should not be printed.  Though 1 has occured has thrice in the 1st array it has not occured in the array 2. So it should also be printed. Please suggest some logic or i should some modifications in this program itself?

Comment: @user3018163 If the suggested solution solved your previous problem, please make sure to mark it as an accepted answer. Regarding the new task, please open a new question for this - because it would be quite confussing otherwise to answer this here in the comments or edit my answer with a solution that doesn't fit the inital problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define NUMCMP(x,y) (((x) < (y)) ? -1 : ((x) > (y)) ? 1 : 0)

#define numcmp(type) int cmp_##type(const void *a, const void *b){\
    type x = *(type*)a;\
    type y = *(type*)b;\
    return NUMCMP(x,y);\
}

numcmp(int);//define function cmp_int

void print_array(int a[], size_t size){
    size_t i;
    printf("{");
    for(i=0;i<size;++i){
        printf("%d", a[i]);
        if(i != size-1)
            printf(",");
    }
    printf("}\n");
}

int main(void){
    int input1[] = {1,1,2,3,3,4,5};
    int input2[] = {4,2,6,7,8};
    size_t input1_size = sizeof(input1)/sizeof(*input1);
    size_t input2_size = sizeof(input2)/sizeof(*input2);

    printf("input1: ");
    print_array(input1, input1_size);
    printf("input2: ");
    print_array(input2, input2_size);

    size_t marge_array_size = input1_size + input2_size;
    int marge_array[marge_array_size];
    memcpy(marge_array, input1, input1_size*sizeof(*input1));
    memcpy(&marge_array[input1_size], input2, input2_size*sizeof(*input2));
    printf("marge array: ");
    print_array(marge_array, marge_array_size);
    qsort(marge_array, marge_array_size, sizeof(*marge_array), cmp_int);
    printf("marge array(after sort): ");
    print_array(marge_array, marge_array_size);

    size_t singles_size = marge_array_size;
    int *singles = malloc(singles_size * sizeof(*singles));
    size_t i;
    int sp;
    bool drop = false;
    for(sp=-1, i=0;i<marge_array_size;++i){
        if(!drop){
            if(sp==-1){
                singles[++sp] = marge_array[i];
                continue;
            }
            if(singles[sp] == marge_array[i]){
                --sp;
                drop = true;
                continue;
            }
        } else if(singles[sp+1] == marge_array[i])
            continue;
        drop = false;
        singles[++sp] = marge_array[i];
    }
    if(sp+1 != singles_size){
        singles_size = sp+1;
        singles = realloc(singles, singles_size*sizeof(*singles));
    }
    printf("marge array(single num): ");
    print_array(singles, singles_size);

    size_t uniques_size = marge_array_size;
    int *uniques = malloc(uniques_size * sizeof(*uniques));
    for(sp=-1, i=0;i<marge_array_size;++i){
        if(sp==-1){
            uniques[++sp] = marge_array[i];
            continue;
        }
        if(uniques[sp] == marge_array[i]){
            continue;
        }
        uniques[++sp] = marge_array[i];
    }
    if(sp+1 != uniques_size){
        uniques_size = sp+1;
        uniques = realloc(uniques, uniques_size*sizeof(*uniques));
    }
    printf("marge array(uniques num): ");
    print_array(uniques, uniques_size);
    //be free uniques and singles 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
  {
     int a[30],b[30];
     int n,k,i,j,p,c=0;
    printf("How many element in first array\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter elements");
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       scanf("%d",&a[i]);                //FIRST ARRAY INPUT
    }


   printf("How many element in second array\n");
  scanf("%d",&k);
  printf("Enter elements");
  for(i=0;i<k;i++)
  {
    scanf("%d",&b[i]);                // SECOND ARRAY INPUT
  }
 printf("The new array is \n");
 for(i=n,j=0;i<(n+k);i++)
   {  
     a[i]=b[j++];                  // MERGE ARRAY B[30],IN A[30] BY EXTEND IT.
   }

 for(i=0;i<(n+k);i++)
   {
     printf("%d ",a[i]);        // PRINT THE MERGED ARRAY
   }
for(i=0,p=0;i<(n+k);i++)        // ELIMINATE DUPLICATE ELEMENTS 
 {
    if(a[i]!=NULL)              
    {

        for(j=i+1;j<(n+k);j++)
        {
            if(a[i]==a[j])       // IF ANY ELEMENTS  MATCH TO NEXT OTHERS ARRAY ELEMENTS THEN, THOSE ELEMENTS ARE ASSIGNED BY NULL.   
            {
                a[j]=NULL;       
            }
        }
        a[p++]=a[i];
        c++;               // COUNTING FOR SIZE OF NEW ARRAY
    }


 }
printf("\nAfter eliminate the duplicate elements,the new array is : \n");
         for(i=0;i<c;i++)
         {
          printf("%d ",a[i]);           // PRINT NEW ARRAY
         }
  return 0;

  }
```

Comment: consider adding some context to your answer: explain what each part is doing, especially because there's a lot of code in your answer. Also, I think you need to fix some indenting.

Comment: Indenting means

Comment: Indenting refers to the tabs before each line. In general, code blocks in deeper layers have more indentation. Your answer, however, does not have consistent spacing.

Comment: note how your spacing is not consistent. code should be aligned - see other answers for examples.